# The Tunnel (Korean) - How come this character has the same name in the old timeline?

Tags: time-travel, timeline, the-tunnel

In the 2017 Korean TV series **[The Tunnel](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6356086/)**, a detective named Park Kwang Ho accidentally time travels from 1986 to 2016 through a mysterious tunnel, while investigating a series of gruesome murders that happen 1986. When he first arrives at 2016, he comes across a young detective who has the *exact full name as him*.

Shortly after arriving at 2016, the protagonist realizes he has gone missing from the 1986 and that has affected his family (wife) and the investigation negatively, and the serial killer has not been caught yet even after 30 years. He realizes that he has to catch the killer in order to return to the past via the tunnel.

He eventually manages to catch the killer with the help of the detectives in the same Police station in 2016 and then returns to 1986 to meet his wife again. He promises the detectives in 2016 that this time, he would catch the killer in 1986 itself (now that he knows the killer's identity) so that they wouldn't have to wait 30 years.

The epilogue shows the new timeline where the protagonist has returned to the past where the protagonist *(has probably caught the killer and)* continues his normal life. Among them, there's a scene that takes place in 1988, where the protagonist helps a woman in labor to reach the hospital from the village. The woman in gratitude gives the newborn boy the same name as the protagonist; Park Kwang Ho. It is implied that newborn boy is the young detective that comes across the protagonist when he first arrives to 2016.

However, this is confusing, as this happens in the **new timeline**; the o*ne where the protagonist returns to the past*. This does not explain the fact how the young detective has the same name as the protagonist in the **old timeline**, where the protagonist does not exist in 1988 and does not help the young detective's mother in labor, which is the reason he gets the same name as the protagonist.

Is there an explanation for this, considering the theories of time-travel and alternate timelines?